# Map the screen cooridanates(X,Y) to bitmap coordinates (X,Y)

Tags: dictionary, bitmap, screen

In my application, need to map the event.getx() and event.gety() values to bitmap image x and y coordinates. one solution is

```
    imageView.getImageMatrix().invert(matrix);
    touchPoint = new float[] { event.getX(),event.getY() };
    matrix.mapPoints(touchPoint);
```

this works fine but in my application i'm not using the Imageview to get matrix instead using Canvas to create the bitmap.Now i've problem to Map the clicked x and y to bitmap image x and y position. Kindly provide any other solution. 
i've already checked getting matrix from canvas passing bitmap as argument but no use.

Regards,
Rakesh